# CIFS mount locks active directory user

Tags: linux-mint, cifs, active-directory

I am configuring a Windows Distributed File share with this fstab entry

`//company.local/DFSdata/Office/office_data  /mnt/y      cifs    credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,noauto,user,vers=3.0, 0       0`

Mounting work fine, but after a couple of hours the active directory user gets locked because of too many bad login attempts.

Here is an example of one of the Windows events

```
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
  <EventID>4776</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Task>14336</Task>
  <Opcode>0</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-09-15T12:36:40.635709300Z" />
  <EventRecordID>90513665</EventRecordID>
  <Correlation />
  <Execution ProcessID="572" ThreadID="2512" />
  <Channel>Security</Channel>
  <Computer>ATSBGDC01.company.local</Computer>
  <Security />
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="PackageName">MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0</Data>
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">user</Data>
  <Data Name="Workstation">ATSBGLINUX01</Data>
  <Data Name="Status">0xc000006a</Data>
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I tested it on another computer with the same Linux distribution with the same results.
I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia.
The same mount works on Ubuntu 18.04.
Any solution or hint how to further debug the problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Is ATSBGLINUX01 this computer? (You don't actually tell us this.)

Comment: yes, ATSBGLINUX01 is the computer which is mounting the DFS share